# PowerShell Workflow - Initial Delay

Tags: powershell, xaml, workflow-foundation

When you first run a PowerShell workflow in a new PS process there is an intial delay as the PS workflow is converted to XAML.  Subsequent runs of the workflow don't experience the same initialization delay.

**Example:**

```
workflow Test-CompilationTime { Write-Output "We ran!" }
```

**First run:**

```
Measure-Command {Test-CompilationTime}

Days : 0 Hours : 0 Minutes : 0 Seconds : 0 Milliseconds : 636
```

**Subsequent Runs:**

```
Measure-Command {Test-CompilationTime}

Days : 0 Hours : 0 Minutes : 0 Seconds : 0 Milliseconds : 64
```

I've experimented with exporting the XAML definition and tried to put it into a PS module with little to no success.

```
(Get-Command Test-CompilationTime).XamlDefinition

<Activity
x:Class="Microsoft.PowerShell.DynamicActivities.Activity_105873347"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.PowerShell.DynamicActivities"
xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:ns0="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.PowerShell.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.PowerShell.Activities"
xmlns:ns2="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
xmlns:ns3="clr-namespace:Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.Activities"
xmlns:ns4="clr-namespace:System.Management.Automation;assembly=System.Management.Automation"
>
<Sequence>
    <ns1:SetPSWorkflowData>
        <ns1:SetPSWorkflowData.OtherVariableName>Position</ns1:SetPSWorkflowData.OtherVariableName>
        <ns1:SetPSWorkflowData.Value>
            <ns2:InArgument x:TypeArguments="ns0:Object">
                <ns1:PowerShellValue x:TypeArguments="ns0:Object" Expression="'2:5:Test-CompilationTime'" />
            </ns2:InArgument>
        </ns1:SetPSWorkflowData.Value>
    </ns1:SetPSWorkflowData>
    <ns3:WriteOutput>
        <ns3:WriteOutput.InputObject>
            <ns2:InArgument x:TypeArguments="ns4:PSObject[]">
                <ns1:PowerShellValue x:TypeArguments="ns4:PSObject[]" Expression="&quot;We ran!&quot;" />
            </ns2:InArgument>
        </ns3:WriteOutput.InputObject>
    </ns3:WriteOutput>
    <Sequence.Variables>
        <Variable Name="WorkflowCommandName" x:TypeArguments="ns0:String" Default = "Test-CompilationTime" />
    </Sequence.Variables>
</Sequence>
```

How do you write a PS workflow so it can be included in a PS module (.psm1) and not experience the workflow --> XAML delay?

Comment: Any function of PS script is compiled on first run.

Comment: I believe I've observed delays with an initial run of a function as well, but nothing as significant as the delay with workflows.

EDIT: helpful but doesn't answer the question on workflows